# Deploying Nuxtjs on CPanel

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, hosting, cpanel

I'm trying to deploy Nuxtjs to cpanel but the pages are not rendering. I have done everything I saw in tutorials on how to fix the issue but none worked. I have used **pms2**, **set hostname** etc but none fixed the issue. Could someone help me out.

Comment: Hi, can you give us more details about what you followed exactly?

Comment: Hi! @kissu, thanks for your swift reply as usual. I followed a blog post [https://jigeshraval.com/en/blog/vue-js/nuxtjs-universal-application-deployment-in-cpanel](https://jigeshraval.com/en/blog/vue-js/nuxtjs-universal-application-deployment-in-cpanel) but I kept having Address error ** FATAL  listen EADDRNOTAVAIL [domain]**. I guess I am doing something wrong probably because I am implementing the solution on localhost.

Comment: The content of package.json would be helpfull in this case.